# Is it possible to change multiple images along with their respective mouseover commands?

Tags: javascript, css

Thanks for looking, I have this plan, I want to create a gallery where I have the main image which is changed by mouse-ing over a bunch of 8 thumbnails, easy.

What I would like to add is separate small bunch of 3 thumbnails and when these are moused over they change the 8 thumbnail images and make them call up 8 new main images. Sorry I hope that’s understandable?

So it’s a little like a tiered or a nested arrangement almost like a small folder tree where the new 3 thumbs hold different libraries of 8 thumbs… no that’s probably just made it even more confusing!!!..

I was keen that it was all done with mouse over the thumbs so it’s smooth and there’s no clicking or reloading the page.

I’ve had a good look around but probably just need telling what terms/phrases/commands to pop in my search engine.

Getting the 3 thumbs to change the 8 thumbs and the main image should be straightforward enough I’m currently using this:

```
<img src = "images/nicepic5thumb.png"  onmouseover =”document.main.src = 'images/nicepic5.jpg';">
```

Where the main big image is:

```
<img src = "images/nicepic1.jpg" name= "main">
```

And I guess it could be expanded to multiple images. Doesn’t have to be done like this however, just whatever would work best, it’s making one mousover change multiple mouseover commands thats currently beyond me.

Ultimately I aim to get all the transitions to fade.

Very grateful for a pointer in the right direction.

Comment: i can try - what do you mean? pop it all togeather into a working html?

Answer (score 0):

I would sent the 3 panels (or more) of 8 thumbs with the respective commands to change main images and make the 3 index thumbs switch the visibility of the 8 images panel

Comment: this sounds within my capabilitys - just about!

Comment: opps i alwasy hit enter half way through when adding comments - neu-rah just to clarify where you thinking of these panales as div's? and please how does one switch the visbility? could they even be faded in? you have an excepted answer heading your way here..!

Answer (score 0):

This is actually something that would be very easy to do in [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com)

All you need to do is add a common class to the images in the gallery or more efficiently add an ID to the element that contains the image and use that to select the images such as.

```
<img src = "images/nicepic1.jpg" name= "main" id="main_img">
<div id="gallery"><img src="nicepic1thumb.png"><img src="nicepic2thumb.png"><img src="nicepic3thumb.png"></div>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#gallery img").onmouseover(function(){
      $("#main_img").attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace("thumb.png",".jpg"));
    }
  }
</script>
```

Here is a full working gallery without animations that does exactly what you wanted.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            gallery.init();
        });
        var gallery = {
            main_img: null,
            init:function(){
                gallery.main_img = $("#main_img img");
                $("#images img").click(function(){
                    gallery.change($(this).attr('src'));
                });
            },
            change: function(image){
                gallery.main_img.attr('src', image.replace("thumb.png",".jpg"));
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="gallery">
    <div id="main_img"><img src="images/image1.jpg"/></div>

    <div id="images">     
        <img src="images/image1thumb.png"/><img src="images/image2thumb.png"/><img src="images/image3thumb.png"/><img src="images/image4thumb.png"/><img src="images/image5thumb.png"/>
    </div>
    </div>
<body>
</html>
```

If you need animations such as fading and stuff just ask.

Comment: thanks very much for this Davan - snag is i'm really quite lost with jquery i'd have to be spoon fed a little more to make this work, sorry!

Comment: I have updated my response to include a gallery that I quickly whipped up using jQuery as an example to you of what I meant.

Comment: This can easily be expanded to be nested as many levels as you wanted.  Or it could be written completely different depending on how you wanted to pull up the images.